# Android-Titanium-Sample project does not fire pushwoosh callback function

Tags: titanium-alloy, pushwoosh

var pushnotifications = require('com.arellomobile.push');
    Ti.API.info("module is => " + pushnotifications);

```
pushnotifications.pushNotificationsRegister("595043289423", "60666-9265D", {
    //NOTE: all the functions fire on the background thread, do not use any UI or Alerts here
    success:function(e)
    {
        Ti.API.info('TITAIUM!!! JS registration success event: ' + e.registrationId);

        alert('TITAIUM!!! JS registration success event: ' + e.registrationId);


    },
    error:function(e)
    {
        Ti.API.error("TITAIUM!!! Error during registration: "+e.error);
        alert("TITAIUM!!! Error during registration: "+e.error);
    },
    callback:function(e) // called when a push notification is received
    {
        alert("in callback");
        Ti.API.info('TITAIUM!!! JS message event: ' + JSON.stringify(e.data));
        //alert('notification data is=' +JSON.stringify("notification data="+e.data));


    }
});
```

Comment: I have import this project form pushwoosh.com but it can not fire callback method.Also i have using titanium version 3.1.2 alloy 1.2.2.